# I am stacking media file download in pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I deployed my Django project to Pythonanywhere.

my directory structure is as follows.

```
/home/myappname/myappname.pythonanywhere.com
 ├── config
 ├── myapp
 ├── template
 ├── static
 └── media
       └── voices
              └── test.mp3
```

I was able to use google-cloud-to-speech to create MP3 files from text and save them to the following media/voices folder.

`/home/myappname/myappname.pythonanywhere.com/media/voices`

When I upload an MP3, the address is stored in the model's Filefield.
After that I checked it in the admin site, it is saved in the DB as follows.

`/home/myappname/myappname.pythonanywhere.com/media/voices/test.mp3`

I could access that MP3 file from Pythonanywhere console. But I could not access it from admin site clicking voice fields.

my browser shows that test.mp3 files address was,

`https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/myappname/files/home/myappname/myappname.pythonanywhere.com/media/voices/test.mp3`

I tried a lot to change MEDIA ROOT or MEDIA but I could not resolve my issue.

Current my MEDIA&STATIC ROOT and MEDIA URL settings are,

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

STATIC files are fine. My web app could display png image which is located at static folder.

[Static files setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8TEy.png)

Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you should be trying to access is `https://myappname.pythonanywhere.com/media/voices/test.mp3`. Whatever is generating the URL that you're trying to access is generating the URL incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll review my code and try your advise today.